# Image do not appear, How to fix this?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image

i have some problem, when i upload image, the image do not appear
NOTE :
gambar -> image

**Index.php**

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();  
        if($('#id_barang').val() == "") {  
            alert("ID Barang is required");  
        } else if ($('#nama_barang').val() == '') {  
            alert("Nama Barang is required");  
        } else if ($('#gambar').val() == '') {  
            alert("Gambar is required");  
        } else {  
            $.ajax({  
                url:"insert.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
                beforeSend:function(){  
                $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
            },  
            success:function(data){  
                $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
                $('#barang_table').html(data);  
            }  
        });  
    }  
});

$(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){
    //$('#dataModal').modal();
    var barang_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url:"select.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: {barang_id:barang_id},
        success:function(data){
        $('#barang_detail').html(data);
        $('#dataModal').modal('show');
     }
  });
 });
});  
</script>
```

Insert.php query for database

```
<?php
//insert.php  
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_test_nutech");
        if(!empty($_POST)) {
            $output = '';
            $id_barang = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["id_barang"]);  
            $nama_barang = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["nama_barang"]);
            //  $gambar = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["gambar"]);
            $harga_beli = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["harga_beli"]);
            $harga_jual = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["harga_jual"]);
            $stock = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["stock"]);
            if (!empty($_FILES['gambar']['name'])) {
                $upload = '../assets/upload/'. basename($_FILES['gambar']['name']);
                $nama_gambar = $_FILES['gambar']['name'];
                $tipe_gambar = $_FILES['gambar']['type'];
                $size_gambar = $_FILES['gambar']['size'];
                $dataTipeGambar = array("image/png","image/jpg/","image/jpeg");

                // jika tipe gambar sama dengan data tipe gambar maka tersedia
                // kalau tidak berarti tipe gambar tidak tersedia atau error
                if (!in_array($tipe_gambar, $dataTipeGambar)) {
                    echo "Tipe Gambar Tidak Tersedia!"; die;
                } else {
                    // move_uploaded_file berfungsi untuk memindahkan sebuah gambar kedalam folder yang kita siapkan untuk gambar
                   if ($size_gambar <= 160000){
                       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['gambar']['tmp_name'], $upload)) {

                           unlink('../assets/upload/'.$row['gambar']);

                           $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO tbl_barang (id_barang,nama_barang, gambar, harga_beli, harga_jual,stock) VALUES ('$id_barang','$nama_barang','$nama_gambar','$harga_beli','$harga_jual','$stock')");
                             if ($query) {
                                 header("location:index.php?tambah=berhasil");
                             } else {
                                 header("location:insert.php?tambah=gagal");
                             }
                         }
                     } else {
                         echo "Max Size Upload Gambar adalah 100KB";die;
                     }
                 }
             } else {
                 $query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO tbl_barang (id_barang,nama_barang, gambar, harga_beli, harga_jual,stock) VALUES ('$id_barang','$nama_barang','$nama_gambar','$harga_beli','$harga_jual','$stock')");
                     if ($query) {
                         header("location:index.php?tambah=berhasil");
                     } else {
                         header("location:insert.php?tambah=gagal");
                     }

                 }
             }
```

**this code and query of my problem..
if need some more code please comment i'll post the rest of code**

[image]

Comment: When you use the browser developer tools to inspect the img element what attributes does it have? What is the src set to? Does that src make sense given your server configuration?

Comment: Do you have any error code inside the developer tools or in the php error log?

Comment: first -> when i upload image, folder image is empty, image cant include to folder upload..
second -> i dont have any error, just cant upload image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your ajax isn't setup for file uploading.

For uploading files you need to set contentType and processdata to false as well as use form data not serialize.

```
var formData = new FormData(this);

$.ajax({  
    url:"insert.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data:formData,  
    beforeSend:function(){  
     $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
    },  
    success:function(data){  
     $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
     $('#barang_table').html(data);  
    }  
   });
```